# How to add text to a graph in diagrammeR

Tags: r

I want to create a nice graph that illustrates some of my data.

I have created the graph but I would like to add some calculated text to the node. How do I do this.

This is my graph but how/ where do I add a field I have calculated in R?:

```
library(magrittr)
library(DiagrammeR)

# Create a simple NDF
nodes <-
create_nodes(nodes = c("Index", "Surveillance", "Intervention", "Lost to Follow-up"))
# Create a simple EDF
edges <-
  create_edges(from = c("Index", "Surveillance", "Index", "Surveillance","Intervention","Surveillance","Intervention"),
               to = c("Surveillance", "Intervention", "Lost to Follow-up", "Lost to Follow-up","Intervention","Surveillance","Lost to Follow-up"),
               )

graph <-
  create_graph(
    nodes_df = nodes,
    edges_df = edges,
    graph_attrs = "layout = twopi",
    node_attrs = "fontname = Helvetica",
    edge_attrs = "color = gray20"
  )

# View the graph
render_graph(graph,output = "visNetwork")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require(visNetwork, quietly = TRUE)

nb = "Information here"

nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:5, group = c(rep("A", 2), rep("B", 3)), 
                    title = paste("<p>", 1:5,"<br>",nb, sep = ""), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
edges <- data.frame(from = c(2,5,3,3), to = c(1,2,4,2))


### USE
visNetwork(nodes, edges, width = "100%") %>% visOptions(highlightNearest = list(enabled =TRUE,algorithm="hierarchical"))
```

You will see your info when you pass the mouse on your node.